# BS4 classes break on HTML Component Refactor in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular6, angular-components

I am currently building components in Angular but I want a certain section to be refactored to a component as this will be reused in other components. When the html block with only bootstrap 4 classes are placed in the parent component, the UI displays correctly.

[image: sidebar section works properly when html block is inline]

However, when I refactor this to another component, the UI breaks despite there are only bootstrap 4 classes appended.

[image: deformed div when extracted as a component]

I have tried different versions of ViewEncapsulation but it doesn't help the situation. I did check the developer tools of Chrome but despite setting ViewEncapsulation.None, there are still some classes sort of appended on the component selector.

I am not sure what I am missing out, but my idea is since the classes being used are just built-in bootstrap 4 classes, I wonder why the UI breaks.

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems that the skills-section has a col-*-4 class being applied (this class is ok when the skill-section is part of the page... occupying 4 columns)... but when you have it in a different component, you have to replace it with col-*-12; this is because when the skills-section goes to a separate component, that separate component should be completely filled (all 12 columns) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on from my comment above, [kindly check this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzw3ml?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html);

- 1st form is as per your first screenshot
- 2nd form is as per your second screenshot - the main issue in your question... which is because you pasted the same class `col-[xx]-4` which you had in form #1
- 3rd form is the solution which i proposed... since the skills is a separate component now, we should put in `col-[xx]-12` as the class inside it

Hope it helps, else you can fork the stackblitz and share your response here in the comments.

Comment: Oh thanks! That worked! although I have to note that similar to your stackblitz link, it didn't occupy the whole block (like as if there's a space to the right). I

Comment: updated the stackBlitz with a new class `.zeroPadding{padding:0px;}` which removes the default padding of the col-[xx]-[99] classes